# SQL Select statement not working properly

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I facing some problem in SQL query.I try to use select result in other select query to get the result but its not working. Can anyone guide me. Below is the code i use in WCF.Thank u very much.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select tName from dbo.tblBankBranch where nBankID=(select nID from dbo.tblBankBranch where tState='" + tBank + "')", con);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: What is the actual problem.  Can you explain "not working".  Is it throwing an exception?  Is it returning nothing?

Comment: it returning nothing & no error coming..

Comment: How do you know what it returned? The code you posted doesn't look at the `SqlDataReader`

Comment: First, make sure the inner select is returning something. If not  you'll need to fix it. If it is, then check that it is returning something that the outer select will see and return.

Comment: Might want to give us brief details into what the table might look like? and the kind of data you want to grab.

Comment: I have try different query, its working fine but when i try to use select within select & i didn't get the results

Comment: John Saunders is right too, after the ExecuteReader you'll need to do a reader.Read() to see if anything is returned.

Comment: Knowing why you're comparing two columns in the same table using a subquery would be useful. What kind of data do nID and nBankID hold? Are they ever actually supposed to equal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you actually get an error that is caught and ignored somewhere.  The SQL statement looks fishy.

```
select tName
from dbo.tblBankBranch
where nBankID=(select nID from dbo.tblBankBranch where tState='{tbank}')
```

It will only work if there is a single branch in the state, otherwise you will get an error.

Try writing it as a JOIN. Ignore that, why have tblBankBranch in there twice?

```
select tName
from dbo.tblBankBranch
where tState='{tbank}'
```

If the fields nBankID and nID are really different in the **single** table, and you do want to link them in that way, then the JOIN form is

```
select A.tName
  from dbo.tblBankBranch A
  join dbo.tblBankBranch B
    on A.nBankID=b.nID AND b.tState='{tbank}'
```

I'll leave it to you to flatten the statements for use in C#.